# removal of repeated string

Tags: java, string

I have a string something like

```
JNDI Locations eis/FileAdapter,eis/FileAdapter used by composite 
HelloWorld1.0.jar are not available in the 
destination domain.
```

eis/FileAdapter,eis/FileAdapter is occuring twice.
I want it to be formatted as

```
 JNDI Locations eis/FileAdapter used by composite 
    HelloWorld1.0.jar are not available in the 
    destination domain.
```

I tried below thing

```
String[ ] missingAdapters =((textMissingAdapterList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim().split(","));
 missingAdapters.get(0)
```

but i am missing second part any better way to handle this?

Comment: will the substring that appears twice always be connected via a comma?

Comment: Yes its connected via comma

Comment: I am getting this from client code which i dont have control hence I like to format it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment below the question you confirm, that the duplicates will alway be conencted via a comma. Using this information, this should work (for most cases):

```
String replaceCustomDuplicates(String str) {
    if (str.indexOf(",") < 0) {
        return str; // nothing to do
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    for (String token : str.split(" ", -1)) {
        if (token.indexOf(",") > 0) {
            String[] parts = token.split(",");
            if (parts.length == 2 && parts[0].equals(parts[1])) {
                token = parts[0];
            }
        } 
        result.append(token + " ");
    }
    return result.delete(result.length() - 1, result.length()).toString();
}
```

a little demo with your example:

```
String str = "JNDI Locations eis/FileAdapter,eis/FileAdapter used by composite";
System.out.println(str);
str = replaceCustomDuplicates(str);
System.out.println(str);
```

> Previous errors fixed

Answer (score 0):

That should do it:

```
String[] missingAdapters = ((textMissingAdapterList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim().split(","));

String result = missingAdapters[0] + " " + missingAdapters[1].split(" ", 2)[1];
```

assuming there is no space in this double string you want to leave out.

Comment: Can you show how to use it? For me, this caused a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` for the given example.

Comment: Downvote, because it will also remove non duplicates: `"ab cd,ef gh"` should not be changed, but it becomes `"ab cd gh"`.

Comment: For the string the OP has this works perfectly. He didn't ask anything else. You delivered a "perfect" answer for every kind of string - I believe that's too much for this question. Please remove the downvote.

Comment: But if he uses this method on any incoming string to clean duplicates, he will lose information in any string that contains commas. Working on just one example is never a good proof. You could simply hardcode that example.

Comment: He will have strings like that. Why else would he name his string `missingAdapters`?

Comment: Sorry, I'll leave my downvote. The question is _removal of repeated string_, your answer is _remove token after first comma_.

Comment: Maybe the OP can clarify things. If my answer suffices you can remove the downvote ;-)

Comment: Sure, but I don't think OP will do anything at all anymore. He's accepted a working solution and is probably going on with his work.

Comment: jlordo thanks your solution address it perfectly Sebastian the solution given by you will work partially not for all usecase.Thanks to you both.